# orphanRemoval working in PostgreSQL but not in hsqldb

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, unit-testing, hsqldb

I have `Academy` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "academy")
public class Academy {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String address;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parent")
private List<Institute> institutes;

public Academy() {}

public Academy(String name, String address, List<Institute> institutes) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.institutes = institutes;
}
```

And `Institute` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "institute")
public class Institute {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column
private String name;

@Column(name = "building_code")
private String buildingCode;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Academy parent;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parent")
private List<Department> departments;


public Institute() {}

public Institute(String name, String buildingCode, Academy parent, List<Department> departments) {
    this.name = name;
    this.buildingCode = buildingCode;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.departments = departments;

    parent.getInstitutes().add(this);
}
```

The idea is that `Academy` is parent, and `Institute`s are childs (tree-like structure). `Institute` has `Department`s - but it does not matter at this moment. I am using `orphanRemoval = true` to remove all `Academy` childs (Institutes etc...) when `Academy` is removed (class `UnitServiceImpl.java`):

```
@Override
@Transactional
public String remove(String whatIsRemoved, Long id) {
    if (whatIsRemoved.equals("academy")){
        Academy academy = getAcademyById(id);
        academy.getInstitutes().clear();
        getCurrentSession().delete(academy);
    }
    else if (whatIsRemoved.equals("institute")){
        Institute institute = getInstituteById(id);
        institute.getParent().getInstitutes().remove(institute);
    }
    //other if's etc..
}
```

And when I'm using aplication, everything seems to be OK - when I delete `Academy` every `Institute` related with this `Academy` and his `Department`s etc.. are removed from database (I am using `PostgreSQL 9.3`). In short - it behaves as tree-like structure. But if I try to write unit tests with in-memory database (i am using `hsqldb` in `2.3.2` version) which should prove it:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void test_WhenAcademyWasRemoved_InstitutesAlsoShouldBeRemoved() throws Exception {
    UnitServiceImpl service = new UnitServiceImpl();
    service.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

    AcademyDTO michigan = new AcademyDTO(null, "Michigan", "test");
    service.saveAcademy(michigan);
    service.saveInstitute(new InstituteDTO(null, "IT", "D", getAcademyIdByName(service, "Michigan"), null));
    service.remove("academy", getAcademyIdByName(service, "Michigan"));

    List<Institute> institutes = (List<Institute>)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Institute.class).list();
    assertEquals(0, institutes.size());
}
```

Instututes related with "Michigan" still are in database with "Michigan" as parent and test crashes. It means that I am wrong and in `PostgreSQL` database also they are not removed (but I check it and `Instututes` was empty) ? Or, it only means that they will be removed when `Transaction` will be commited? Because test method needs to be `@Transactional`, without it test won't compile - but then, how to test it? I am stuck, because in app it looks OK, but in unit test with in-memory database it does not work as I think it should. I will be very pleased if anybody helps me - thank you in advance.
**UPDATE:** The question is: `orphanRemoval = true`works on localhost database, in my opinion because transaction is commited and then cascade delete is applied. How can I do the same thing in not very complicated way in unit tests - like commit transaction (which triggers cascade delete) before test ends and then get `Institute`s with another `Transaction`? I tried private `@Transactional` methods in test but it doesn't work.

Comment: I find this quite confusing to read, and I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CraigRinger I'll precise my question within few minutes

Comment: And another good example why it doesn't make sense to use a different DBMS for testing and production....

Comment: What do you mean without Transactional annotation it does not compile? This is hard to believe. What compiler error do you get?

Comment: @JensSchauder I get error about lack of sinchronized transaction - same like when I forget about `@Transactional` on Service method... Which is weird because I think when System Under Test methods are annotated with `@Transactional` I shouldn't make test `@Transactional`... But unfortunately, I have to.

Comment: At compile time?????

Comment: @JensSchauder of course not :) My mistakes, I wrote it early morning, just before work - of course all compile ok but didn't work ( i got standard erros about no active transaction), but now with your advice everything is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be that Transactions in tests are handled differently than in "normal" code (something that confuses myself over and over again).

Let's verify that I understand your question correct:

When you run the application using a mysql database everything works fine.

But when you run your test against a hsqldb cascade delete seems to fail.

I think the difference between the two scenarios is the handling of transactions and more importantly the time when changes get flushed from the session into the database, i.e. sql statements get actually executed.

To verify this you can activate sql logging to see when exactly your data gets stored in the database. My expectation is that in production this happens at the latest at the end of each @Transactional method, but in test everything runs in a single transaction due to the @Transactional annotation on the test and no flush happens, or at least not at the same point in time.

In order to simulate the production behavior you can add calls to `Session.flush` at the places where normally a transaction ends.

Comment: I call `Session.flush` after any thing that modify DB (save, remove etc) and it works correctly, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that spring AOP wont cut private methods for @Transactional. Try making the test utility method public and then call again. Hope it works!